# Best way of removing single newlines but keeping multiple newlines

Tags: python, newline

What would be the most pythonic way of removing single newlines but keeping multiple newlines from a string?

As in

`"foo\n\nbar\none\n\rtwo\rthree\n\n\nhello"`

turning into

`"foo\n\nbar one two three\n\n\nhello"`

I was thinking about using splitlines(), then replacing empty lines by `"\n"` and then concatenating everything back again, but I suspect there is a better/simpler way. Maybe using regexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> re.sub('(?<![\r\n])(\r?\n|\n?\r)(?![\r\n])', ' ', s)
'foo\n\nbar one two three\n\n\nhello'
```

This looks for `\r?\n` or `\n?\r` and uses lookbehind and lookahead assertions to prevent there from being a newline on either side.

For what it's worth, there are three types of line endings found in the wild:

1. `\n` on Linux, Mac OS X, and other Unices
2. `\r\n` on Windows, and in the HTTP protocol
3. `\r` on Mac OS 9 and earlier

The first two are by far the most common. If you want to limit the possibilities to just those three, you could do:

```
>>> re.sub('(?<![\r\n])(\r?\n|\r)(?![\r\n])', ' ', s)
'foo\n\nbar one two three\n\n\nhello'
```

And of course, get rid of the `|\r` if you don't care about Mac line endings, which are rare.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. But now that I'm reading, I don't think that looking for `'\r\n'` or even single `'\r'` makes much sense. Maybe the only sensible newlines are `'\n'` and `'\n\r'`. Is that right? If so, could you also provide the regex for the simpler case?