# How to tidy up paragraph using python?

Tags: python

I recently downloaded a book in pdf format and copy pasted the text from the pdf to notepad and saved it as book.txt. The problem I'm having now is that the book has around 29,000 lines, line by line.
The paragraphs in the book.txt are not continuous instead they take a new line after a set of words as below

```
The project manager selected a professional team with a long practical
experience in this field which comes to around twenty years. This team is
unique in the fact that their area of experience and expertise is mainly in
dealing with this genre of texts
```

When you notice after the word 'practical' the word 'experience' begins with new line But I want the paragraphs to be continuous as below

```
The project manager selected a professional team with a long practical experience in this field which comes to around twenty years. This team is unique in the fact that their area of experience and expertise is mainly in dealing with this genre of texts. The team started their job keeping in mind the importance of the task and the objective the author (of the Arabic book) was trying to realize from this project.
```

All the text in the book.txt are in the same format.

With python how can I correct this for the whole book so that each paragraph is continuous?

Comment: How are paragraphs separated from each other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way of removing single newlines but keeping multiple newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649851/best-way-of-removing-single-newlines-but-keeping-multiple-newlines)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65111582/how-do-i-replace-n-in-a-string-but-not-n-n-in-python

Comment: @C_Z_ there is a `\n` after each line and paragraphs are not seperated but when we look at the text we would know that this is a paragraph.

Comment: "when we look at the text we would know that this is a paragraph." If there's no way to distinguish paragraphs except by human intuition, then it's practically impossible to have a computer divide them up objectively.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its all simple \n this will fix your problem:

```
a_file = open("book.txt", "r")


string_without_line_breaks = ""

for line in a_file:

    stripped_line = line.replace('\n', " ")

    string_without_line_breaks += stripped_line



a_file.close()

formattedbookString = string_without_line_breaks.replace('  ', '\n\n')

text_file = open("formattedBook.txt", "w")
text_file.write(formattedbookString)
text_file.close()
```

We are opening your file in python (asuming its in the same directory as your .py script):

```
a_file = open("book.txt", "r")
```

We create an empty string to save your book in and we read in each line in your txt. While we replace a single newline with a space and concatenate all of them:

```
string_without_line_breaks = ""

for line in a_file:

    stripped_line = line.replace('\n', " ")

    string_without_line_breaks += stripped_line
```

We are closing the file stream and now we are using replace to take the double whitespaces which result from the replacing of '\n' with " " and replace them with a newline '\n'

```
a_file.close()

formattedbookString = string_without_line_breaks.replace('  ', '\n\n')
```

At last we create a new file where we save your book.

```
text_file = open("formattedBook.txt", "w")
text_file.write(formattedbookString)
text_file.close()
```

Your formatted book should be available in your filesystem where your pythonscript sits.

Comment: Thank you Mldoehmer, but the above script merges multiple paragraphs into one i.e. it merges all the paragraph of one section of the book into a big paragraph. rather I want the individual paragraph to be seperated from every other paragraph.

Comment: should be fixed by now :) at least in my test.

Comment: I'm sorry Mldoehmer, the above script did not solve the issue rather it merges all the paragraphs in one big section.